# If URL equals this then do this

Tags: php, jquery

So I've successfully used both of the following domain checking methods before to perform some action, but it was always for a specific page (ending in .php or something). Now I want to do the same check on my home page, which always shows up as domain.com, with no following /index.php or anything, but I can't get either of these methods to work. I've been testing this on the dev server, hence the dev.domain.com

The reasoning is that I have a script that I only want to run on my home page, and the CMS and script being the way it is, the easiest way is to build something into the template so it only fires on the home page.

Here's the php and js methods that I haven't been able to get to work:

```
<?php
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($host == 'dev.domain.com') {
include("/js/cover.js");
}
else
{
include("/js/nocover.js"); 
}
?>


<script>
if (location.href.indexOf("dev.domain.com") !== -1)
{
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#cover').delay(500).fadeOut(500);
});     
}
</script>
```

EDIT 1: So it should look like this?

```
<?php

if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'dev.domain.com')
{
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'dev.domain.com')
{
include("js/cover.js");
}
else
{
include("js/unclick.js"); 
}
}

?>
```

Comment: have you tried using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`?

Comment: Check if the REQUEST_URI includes a `/`. You might actually be making $host be `dev.domain.com/`, which'd then fail your `if $host ==` stuff.

Comment: Are you seeing any javascript errors in the page. my suspect is whether the js is included properly or not. Or else you can try doing this 
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 if (location.href.indexOf("dev.domain.com") !== -1){    
  jQuery('#cover').delay(500).fadeOut(500);
 }
);     
</script>

Answer (score 3):

The value you are looking for is in `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'dev.domain.com') {
```

Might be advisable to wrap it in `strtolower()` I suppose, but I think most clients send it as lowercase regardless of user input.

`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` will contain the server name value defined in the web server config. This may not match the host name that was used to access the page, which I imagine is what you actually want. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains the path the file that was requested, relative to document root. You are not comparing against the page that was requested, simply against the host name, so you do not need this here.

**EDIT**

Upon closer inspection, it looks like the problem you are haing is actually with the paths that you are passing to `include`. Remember that `include` uses **local file system** paths, *not* the same path structure that you use from a browser. It is likely that all you need to do is remove the leading `/` from your paths, like:

```
include("js/cover.js"); 
//      ^^ remove the slash from here
```

As it is you are trying to include a file from the root of the file system in a directory called `/js` - which I highly doubt actually exists. You would use a relative path for this situation, so just drop the slash.

Comment: I can't get either of the files in the include statements to show up, even the else, which doesn't make sense. I tried your method and the one I was using, same result. I'm 100% sure the paths are correct, I can paste them into a browser and open them just fine.

Comment: Ahhhh... wait, hang on, I see the problem. See edit in 1 minute.

Comment: Ah ha, that did it! But it looks like the first file is being included on every page, such as domain.com/products.html rather than only domain.com. Any way we can prevent this?

Comment: Ok, thats when you do need `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` (although I prefer `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`). If your file name is `index.php`, wrap your `if` in another, outer `if`: `if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'index.php') {`